# JScrollPane in Jlist

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, null-layout-manager

hello goodevening to all i have a problem on my program with the ScrollPane in my JList i cant put an JScrollPane in my list because i am using a panel instead of Container this is my code so far its all runnable the problem is if you enter a high number in the number of times the some output will not be able to see because of the size of my list . so this is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MultCen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        MultCen e = new MultCen();
        e.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        e.setVisible(true);
        e.setSize(300,450);
    }

    JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
    JButton b = new JButton("Okay");
    JButton c = new JButton("Clear");
    JList list = new JList();
    JLabel lab = new JLabel();
    DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();

    public MultCen()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);



        JLabel l = new JLabel("Enter a number :");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("How many times :");



        l.setBounds(10,10,130,30);
        l1.setBounds(10,40,130,30);
        t1.setBounds(140,10,130,25);
        t2.setBounds(140,40,130,25);
        b.setBounds(60,90,75,30);
        c.setBounds(150,90,75,30);
        list.setBounds(30,140,220,220);

        panel.add(t1);
        panel.add(t2);
        panel.add(l);
        panel.add(l1);
        panel.add(list);
        panel.add(b);
        panel.add(c);

        getContentPane().add(panel);


        b.addActionListener(this);
        c.addActionListener(this);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == b)
        {
            int t3 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            int t4 = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
            m.addElement("The multiplication Table of "+t3);
            for (int cc =1 ; cc <=t4; cc++ )
            {

                lab.setText(t3+"*"+cc+" = "+(t3*cc));
                m.addElement(lab.getText());
                list.setModel(m);


            }



        }

        if(e.getSource() == c)
        {
            t1.setText("");
            t2.setText("");
            m.removeAllElements();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _"i cant put an JScrollPane in my list "_ - list goes in the scroll pane, not the other way around.

Comment: _"because i am using a panel instead of Container"_ - a panel _is_ a container

Comment: Don't use null layouts. Use [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: sir in the other layout do i need to relocate those buttons and textfields ?

Comment: Using layout managers you don't need to _"locate"_ anything. You position them by either nesting panels or using a layout manager like `GridBagLayout` that helps with _"location"_. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JScrollPane` does not work with `null` Layout. Use `BoxLayout` or any other resizeable layout instead. This is the limitation of `setLayout(null)`.

Comment: How sir ? can i setBounds in BoxLayout ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Layout managers. You've asked a lot of questions here and I'm sure a few you have been advised not to use null layout. Again here is the tutorial [**Laying out components Within a container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Learn to use them so you don't run into the million possible problems on the road ahead. *This* kind of problem being one of them.

here's an example of how you could achieve the same thing with layout managers, and some empty borders for white space.

**With Layout Manager**

[image]

**Without Layout Manger**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MultCen extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MultCen e = new MultCen();
                e.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                e.setVisible(true);
                e.pack();
            }
        });

    }

    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton b = new JButton("Okay");
    JButton c = new JButton("Clear");
    JLabel lab = new JLabel();
    DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();

    public MultCen() {

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 5));
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Enter a number :");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("How many times :");
        topPanel.add(l);
        topPanel.add(t1);
        topPanel.add(l1);
        topPanel.add(t2);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(b);
        buttonPanel.add(c);
        buttonPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));

        JList list = new JList();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 15, 10, 15));

        getContentPane().add(panel);

    }
}
```

---

**Side Notes**

- Run Swing apps from the Event Dispatch Thread. See [**Initial Threads**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- When you *do* decide to use layout managers, just `pack()` your frame instead of `setSize()`
- Use better variable names.
- See [**Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the the program**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-the-program)