# ActionListener gets an error it says(Finals is not abstract and does not override abstract method)

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Finals extends Frame implements  WindowListener,ActionListener{
public TextField tf1;
public Button btn0,btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9,btnadd,btnminus,btndivide,btnmultiply,btnequals,btnbackspace;

public Finals(){

    Panel outputpanel = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
     tf1 = new TextField(" ",30);
     outputpanel.add(tf1);

    Panel btnpanel = new Panel(new GridLayout (5,5));

     btn0 = new Button ("0");
     btn1 = new Button ("1");
     btn2 = new Button ("2");
     btn3 = new Button ("3");
     btn4 = new Button ("4");
     btn5 = new Button ("5");
     btn6 = new Button ("6");
     btn7 = new Button ("7");
     btn8 = new Button ("8");
     btn9 = new Button ("9");

     btnadd= new Button("+");
     btnminus = new Button("-");
     btndivide = new Button ("/");
     btnmultiply = new Button ("*");
     btnequals = new Button ("=");
     btnbackspace= new Button("<-");

    btnpanel.add(btnadd);
    btnpanel.add(btnminus);
    btnpanel.add(btndivide);
    btnpanel.add(btnmultiply);
    btnpanel.add(btnequals);
    btnpanel.add(btnbackspace);

    btnpanel.add(btn1);
    btnpanel.add(btn2);
    btnpanel.add(btn3);
    btnpanel.add(btn4);
    btnpanel.add(btn5);
    btnpanel.add(btn6);
    btnpanel.add(btn7);
    btnpanel.add(btn8);
    btnpanel.add(btn9);
    btnpanel.add(btn0);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(outputpanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(btnpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible (true);
    setSize (300,200);
    setTitle("Calculator");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    addWindowListener(this);
}

public static void mainr(String[]args){
        Finals awt = new Finals();    
}

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
            System.exit(0);
        }
     public void windowClosed(WindowEvent we){};
     public void windowOpened(WindowEvent we){};
     public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we){};
     public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent we){};
     public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we){};
     public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent we){};
}
```

Comment: what is `mainr`? please copy and past your code.. don't type..

Comment: Paste the Stack trace too.

Comment: Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented interface `ActionListener` so need to override `actionPerformed`  method from that interface otherwise declare your class as `abstract`.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //your code goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to `implements` an `interface` (`ActionListener`), Then you need to @Override all of it's methods. In this case you need to implement the `actionPerfomed` method for your `Finals` class

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // do something
}
```

---

- Also, what is `public static void mainr(String[]args){`? `mainr` should be `main`
- Also, make use of the `@Override` anotation, so you know you have successfully overridden a method, i.e.

  ```
  @Override
  public void windowClossing(WindowEvent e) {}
  ```
- Also, Swing apps should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You can do so by wrapping the inside of your `main` method with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater...`. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- Also, you should `setVisible(true)` *after* `setSize` and `setLocationXxx`
- Also, you should just `pack()` your frame, instead of `setSize()` so that all the components are *sure* to be visibly contained.
- Also read up on [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-the-program)
- Also, why AWT and not Swing? Look into using Swing. See more at [Creating GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: OPs uses AWT Frame/Panel etc :-)