# No connection between JTree nodes and JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jtree, mouselistener

I cannont make a connection between JTree nodes and JPanel.
I have JTree nodes: blue and violet and JPanel1 and JPanel2.
Node blue must connect with JPanel1 and violet with JPanel2.
But when I click nodes nothing happens.
I do not know what is wrong. Can somebody help?
Here is code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


public class Tree extends javax.swing.JFrame {
static String lastComponent = "";
final JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test App");
    /**
     * Creates new form Tree
     */
    public Tree() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTree2 = new javax.swing.JTree();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode1 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("JTree");
        javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode2 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("colors");
        javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("blue");
        treeNode2.add(treeNode3);
        treeNode3 = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode("violet");
        treeNode2.add(treeNode3);
        treeNode1.add(treeNode2);
        jTree2.setModel(new javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel(treeNode1));
        jTree2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTree2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTree2);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, "card2");

        jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jPanel2.add(jButton1, "card2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 264, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTree2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        TreePath path = jTree2.getPathForLocation(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        if (path != null) {

            if (!lastComponent.equals("")) {
                if (lastComponent.equals("blue")) {
                    jf.remove(jPanel1);
                } else if (lastComponent.equals("violet")) {
                    jf.remove(jPanel2);
                }
            }

            if (path.toString().contains("blue")) {
                jf.add(jPanel1);
                lastComponent = "blue";
            } else if (path.toString().contains("violet")) {
                jf.add(jPanel2);
                lastComponent = "violet";
            }
            jf.repaint();
        }
    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tree().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTree jTree2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You do realize that your class is the JFrame that all the components in `initComponents` are being added to, right? Yet you are creating another instance frame `jf` that you are trying to do those operations on

Answer (score 2):

First of all instead of `MouseListener` you should attach a [TreeSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionListener.html) if you want to listen to selection changes. See [Responding to Node Selection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select).

On the other hand at these lines:

```
if (path.toString().contains("blue")) {
    jf.add(jPanel1); // <-- here
    lastComponent = "blue";
} else if (path.toString().contains("violet")) {
    jf.add(jPanel2); // <-- here
    lastComponent = "violet";
}
```

As @peeskillet wisely pointed out you're trying to add a `JPanel` to a `JFrame` (jf) which is actually a class member hidding your class (also a `JFrame`). Since you seem to be using some GUI builder (NetBeans' I think) you could either:

- Get rid of this class member and add panels to your class instead.
- Get rid of GUI builder and use just a local variable instead (strongly recommended). See [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-the-program)

Finally you might want to consider use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and switch cards based on nodes selection instead of add-revalidate-repaint process.

Comment: Good catch! I'll edit my answer to include your observation :D @peeskillet

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. I will consider your answers.

Comment: You guys very clever I have ever seen, respect from me