# How to avoid "put on top of" a component another component - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have two components ready to add to frame:

```
class Lamina extends JPanel{

    public Lamina(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(50,50));

        JPasswordField user_password = new JPasswordField();
        add(user_password, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

}

class DOMHeader extends JPanel
{
    public DOMHeader()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Sign in");
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

This is my class UI:

```
public class UI {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setTitle("Metin2");

    }  
}
```

Frame class:

```
class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        Toolkit screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize = screen.getScreenSize();

        int widthScreen = screenSize.width;
        int heightScreen = screenSize.height;

        setBounds((widthScreen/4/2),(heightScreen/4/2),(widthScreen/2/2), (heightScreen/2/2));

        Image icon = screen.getImage("icon.jpeg");

        setIconImage(icon);


        /* Add to Components to frame*/
        add(new DOMHeader());
        add(new Lamina());

    }

}
```

In my class Frame I'm adding the components shown earlier, but it "put on top of" a component another component.

According to the API:

```
public Component add(Component comp,int index)
```

> Adds the specified component to this container at the given position
>   (index).

I run the main method:

[image]

As you can see it only show the Component `DOMHeader` class: `add(new DOMHeader())`

And what happened with `add(new Lamina())`

What number or Constant I should give it ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Using null layout will add every component at 0,0, you should go with a LayoutManager such AxisLayout, the index is only used to determine which component is draw first (the first one is on bottom of others)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos he's not using `null layout`. He just called `setBounds(...)` on the `JFrame` itself to position it on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
class Frame extends JFrame {
```

is incorrect for the following reasons:

1. It's confusing because of AWT [`Frame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) class
2. It extends `JFrame` but you never change the behavior of the `JFrame` later, so no need to extend `JFrame` but [create it inside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program)

Now, we must head to [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class in which says:

> The default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it.

Now, if we go to the visual guide for layout managers in the [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) section we can see the following image:

[image]

Which shows us that we can only add our components to 5 locations:

- `PAGE_START` (or `NORTH`)
- `LINE_START` (or `WEST`)
- `CENTER`
- `LINE_END` (or `EAST`)
- `PAGE_END` (or `SOUTH`)

To answer your question:

> According to the API:
>
> ```
> public Component add(Component comp,int index)
> ```
>
> > Adds the specified component to this container at the given position (index).
>
> What number or Constant I should give it ?

Well you need to add it as follows:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Write your title here"); //Follow first advice
frame.add(new DOMHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH); //These are the constants.
frame.add(new Lamina(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

You confused yourself by adding the items in their locations in their own `JPanel`s not on the `JFrame` itself.

**Side note:** Why are you doing these weird calculations?

```
setBounds((widthScreen/4/2),(heightScreen/4/2),(widthScreen/2/2), (heightScreen/2/2));
```

Wouldn't it be clearer if you called: `widthScreen / 8`?

---

As per @camickr comment:

> There is no need for the DOMHeader and Lamina classes. You don't need to extend JPanel just to add a component to the frame. The "content pane" of a JFrame is a JPanel, so you can just add the label and text field to the frame as shown above.

You can also have your code improved in this way:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Your title here");
JLabel title = new JLabel("Sign in");
JPasswordField userPassword = new JPasswordField(); //changed variable name to userPassword instead of user_password to follow Java naming conventions

frame.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(userPassword, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

frame.setVisible(true); //This line should be the last one or you'll find yourself with strange "bugs" when your application starts until you move it or resize it
```

No need to create a whole new `JPanel` for each component.

Comment: There is no need for the DOMHeader and Lamina classes. You don't need to extend JPanel just to add a component to the frame. The "content pane" of a JFrame is a JPanel, so you can just add the label and text field to the frame as shown above.

Comment: Nice catch @camickr I just focused on the main problem and didn't noticed it. I just added an edit following your comment :)

Comment: Thank you @Frakcool , I'm sorry for my bad code, I'am beginner. Your answer was very useful

Comment: It wasn't bad at all, but it could be improved, we all were beginners at some time so keep it up. Just pay attention to suggestions so you can improve :) cheers @jjoselon