# How can one update and add to a JList from another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two `JFrames`.

`AddSongFrame` takes in the user input through `jTextFields` and `MusicPlayerandLibraryForm` updates the `jList` with the user input.

However, I have run into a problem with adding elements to the `jList`. At the line

```
MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm mplf = new MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm();
```

it seems that the `JFrame` is not updating the `jList`. It clears the `jList` and then adds the `songName` to the `jList`.

How can I access the `JFrame` in a way where it doesn't clear the `jList` when the user accesses another `jFrame`?

```
public class AddSongFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
        ArrayList<Song> songFileLibrary = new ArrayList<Song>();
        DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();

        int currentIndex = 0;



        public AddSongFrame() {
            initComponents();
        }


        private void jButtonBrowseFilesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
           JFileChooser fileBrowser = new JFileChooser();
           fileBrowser.showOpenDialog(null);
           File f = fileBrowser.getSelectedFile();
           String fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
           jTextFieldFileName.setText(fileName);

        }                                                  

        private void jButtonAddSongActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

            String fileName = jTextFieldFileName.getText();
            String songName = jTextFieldSongName.getText();
            String songGenre = jTextFieldSongGenre.getText();
            String songArtist = jTextFieldArtist.getText();

            Song song = new Song(songName, fileName, songGenre, songArtist);
            Song songFiles = new Song(fileName,songName, songGenre,songArtist);
            songs.add(song);
            songFileLibrary.add(songFiles);


            updatejListMusicLibrary();

        }                                              



        private void updatejListMusicLibrary()
        {

            MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm mplf = new MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm();
            MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm.getjListMusicLibrary().setModel(dlm);
            mplf.setDlmMain(dlm);
            this.setVisible(false);
            mplf.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the behavior you're having is, but a [mcve] might be better than the current code as we don't have access to `Song` code nor `MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm`. Please go through the [help], take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question, so your question can receive more and better answers.

Comment: Also read [The use of multiple JFrames, good / bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) (The general consensus is: it's bad). better to use `Dialog`s or `CardLayout` and build your GUI towards the use of `JPanel`s instead of `JFrame`s. As you're not changing the behavior of the `JFrame` and so, there's no need to `extend` it. See [extends JFrame or create it inside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program)

Comment: The reason for the list being deleted on new `JFrame` click is that it's creating a new `List` on every click, but it's hard to tell without being able to reproduce the problem, and thus a MCVE might solve many of our doubts and point to the root of the problem and probably some minor other ones you might have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is more than likely here:

```
MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm mplf = new MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm();
```

This is being called everytime you click your `JButton` and it create a new instance of `MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm` everytime.

You need to create an instance of this class only once, then use that instance to update the `JList`, however this line:

```
MusicPlayerAndLibraryForm.getjListMusicLibrary()
```

Tells me that `getjListMusicLibrary()` is a `static` method and shows an problem of design in your program.

However as I already said in the comments above, avoid [the use of multiple JFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) and use [`Dialogs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) or a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#card) for asking user for information and then use it to update the single instance of the `JList` in the `JFrame`. As I said, also avoid [extending JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program) and create an instance of it inside your class.

Answer (score -3):

You can make the list static and then create a method in your JFrame class which calls the static list and adds to it, when the button or any other thing is pressed in the JFrame...

Hope this Helps.....

Comment: static is not an answer - if the op creates more instances of the class they will more problems