# Paint Method is not Called

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint

After making an instance in a previous frame, I'm trying to the background image on the next frame but as a result, I just saw the debugged result and found out that the paint method was not called. From what I know, the paint method is inherited by the JFrame class and with this logic, I've made it overrided. As I guess, the reason happen the logical error is from what I used the event handler and made the instance in the EventHandlerClass.

```
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals(ButtonTo))       
        if(idString.equals("USER"))
                {                       
                    {
                        if("1234".equals(pwSt))     
                        {
                            System.out.println("Wellcome");
                            if(gs==null)
                            {
                                gs=new GameStart();
                            }
                        }
                    else
                    {
                         System.out.println("Confirm your password");
                    }               
                    }           
                }
```

This is a code that If an action is performed it will make an instance(gs). After doing this, I noticed that the instance has been used as to make a new console frame.

```
class GameStart extends JFrame {
    private Image screenImage;
    private Graphics screenGraphic;
    private Image introBackgroundImage;
    private ImageIcon img;

    GameStart()
    {
        JFrame jf=new JFrame("Game Set");
        jf.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 200);
        jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton bt1=new JButton("Start");
        JButton bt2=new JButton("Exit");    
        JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
        panel1.add(bt1);panel1.add(bt2);

        setContentPane(panel1);

        jf.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bt1.addActionListener(new Choice());
        bt2.addActionListener(new Choice());
        jf.setVisible(true);    
        img=new ImageIcon("./Images/backGroundImage.jpg");
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        screenImage=createImage(200, 200);  
        screenGraphic=screenImage.getGraphics();
        screenDraw(screenGraphic);
        g.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0, null);
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    public void screenDraw(Graphics g) 
    {   
        this.repaint();
        System.out.println("3");
    }
```

Now, With making a frame and some buttons, I expect to show all the numbers(1, 2, 3) that indicate the result but Just did number 1.

Comment: Don't override paint() on a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get your started. You can also check out [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which is a class that you can use to easily display an image as a background.

Comment: Can you please flesh out your code example? In particular, you have an `if` statement that should be inside a method which is inside a class.

Comment: *"in a previous frame"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Please post [mcve] including `createImage()`. **Do not** call `repaint` from within `paint`

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code that I can see at first glance:

1. You're extending `JFrame`, but you're not adding any extra functionality to it, see: [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program). Instead, build your GUI towards the use of `JPanel`s and override their `paintComponent(...)` method and not the `paint(...)` one.
2. You're breaking the paint-chain: After doing the above point, in `paintComponent()`, call `super.paintComponent(...)`

Maybe there are others but I'm currently busy and can't test your code, but the ones above should help with your issue.